# Play2 Framework - Scala - Silhouette check token manually

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I'm using Play Framework with Scala to build a RESTful API. To implement authentication I'm using the `play-silhouette` plugin, with the use of a `BearerTokenAuthenticator`. It works perfectly.

The problem is that I must implement a service that use a WebSocket to push real-time updates, but I can't manage to setup user authentication for this method.

Silhouette provides support to do that ([doc](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/v3.0/docs/endpoints)), the problem is that I can't find a way to put the token in the header of the websocket handshake requests. I did a lot of research, but without any result.

I thought that I could pass the token in the query string, instead of passing it in the request header.

My question is, how can I validate a token manually with silhouette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. I've created an [issue](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/issues/390) to fix this with the help of a [request extractor](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/api/util/RequestExtractor.scala#L28).

In the meantime you could override the [retrieve](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/silhouette/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/authenticators/BearerTokenAuthenticator.scala#L110) method of the `BearerTokenAuthenticatorService` and use the value from query string instead of the header.

Comment: Looks to be [merged](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/pull/390) and part of Silhouette 4.0